# Given $f(z)=(-z(1+i\sqrt{3}))^{1/3}$, evaluate $f(1)$ and $f(8)$ in the branch in which $\pi/3<\arg(f(z)) \leq \pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Please let me know where I made a mistake, I just couldn't find that branch, and thank you!

So I represented this in polar form with magnitude: $(4(x^2+y^2))^{1/6}$, and argument: $\frac{\tan^{-1}(y/x)+\pi/3+2\pi k}{3}.$

Or simply as $f(z)=[4(x^2+y^2)]^{1/6}e{\frac{\arg(-z)+\pi/3+2\pi k}{3}}$.

Taking the branches $k=0,1,2$ I didn't get those bounds... I got:

1. For $k=0 \rightarrow -2\pi/9 < \arg(f(z)) \leq 4\pi/19$.
2. For $k=1 \rightarrow 4\pi/9 < \arg(f(z)) \leq 10\pi/9$.
3. For $k=2 \rightarrow 10\pi/9 < \arg(f(z)) \leq 16\pi/9$.

The second branch is actually the desired branch but it's off by $\frac{\pi}{9}$, as $\frac{4\pi}{9}=\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{10\pi}{9}=\frac{\pi}{9}+\pi$. It almost seems like whoever made the problem forgot that $f(z)$ had the third root.

Is it a mistake in the problem or mine? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

We have to solve $$w^3=-\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) z$$ for $z=1;z=8$
$$w^3=-\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi\right) \right)$$
has three solutions
$$w_k=\sqrt[3]{2}\left(\cos\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi+2k\pi\right)+i\sin\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\pi+2k\pi\right)\right);\quad k=0,1,2$$
$$w_0=\sqrt[3]{2}\left(\cos\frac{4}{9}\pi+i\sin\frac{4}{9}\pi\right)$$

$w_1,w_2$ have an arg larger than $\pi$.

In a similar way can be solved $$w^3=-8\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)$$